# nodejs property undefined

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I defined:

- a mongoose schema (Type1) to save an object
- 2 others that extends the first schema (Type2 and Type3) with other properties (content, and others...).

When I load an object Type1 saved as Type 2 from the database, I can access all properties except for one (The content property). But if I do an `object.toString()` the property does exist.

How is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: So, no code, no output of `object.toString()`, no nothing? And you expect somebody to help you blindly?

Comment: Doing object.toString() the string has all the properties loaded from database, but I have not access to the properties of Type2 or Type3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties of mongoose objects are always the same as its schema. Loaded as a `Type1` schema will have properties of `Type1` schema.

The underlying data may be bigger (because of Schema inheritance or simply because someone stored more data directly in MongoDB), but you cannot access it from the level of `Type1` using only properties. The method you can try using (didn't test it) is `object.getValue('content');`. Also, I think that `object._doc` holds the real data from DB.

One last thing: `object.toString` is actually overriden and it shows `inspect` of entire object. That's why you see the underlying data.